# Firebase Swift Retrieve retrieve single child

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This has been asked before, but I'm stuck on this for a long time now and no research has been able to solve my problem. Maybe it's something really obvious, so I apologize in advance.

Here is my database:

```
- Users
  - 6tZ7OMXa86XFo9auvke4dA4SPJX2 // this is the UID
    - email: "billyjoe@gmail.com" 
    - name: "Billy Joe"
    - points: "5" // -->> The value I want to retrieve.
```

[Here is a pic if would like to see the actual database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgMHu.png)

I'm trying to retrieve the points by doing this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var pointsTextField: UILabel!

var ref: DatabaseReference!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    userIdTextField.text = userID
    ref = Database.database().reference().child("Users").child(userID!).child("points")

    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) {
        (snapshot) in
        if let points = snapshot.value as? Int {
            self.pointsTextField.text = "\(points)"
        }
    }
```

I've also tried adding the children nodes before the "observeSingleEvent" and restructure it, but my label is always coming back without the 5. 
I've tested the UID and it's correct. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: try retrieving the entire user object by setting ref = Database.database().reference().child("Users").child(userID!). .. lets see what it gives

Comment: I's not returning anything. When I put a breakpoint it says points = (int) 4399649672, but I guess it also gave me a number like that when I had all children

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are storing points as String and retriving it as Int

```
    if let points = snapshot.value as? String {
        self.pointsTextField.text = "\(points)"
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help. That solved the problem.